# Plotly animation without interpolation

Tags: python, animation, plotly, interpolation

I am using Python's plotly.express.line to do an animation. Is it possible to make the transition from frame to frame without interpolation? I am trying with `fig.update_layout(transition={'easing': bla_bla_bla})` but cannot make it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- have created an animated line to demonstrate
- `fig.layout.updatemenus[0].buttons[0].args[1]["transition"]["duration"] = 0` means play button jumps between frames and there is no transition between frames
- **easing** is already set to **linear** in this animated figure

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "x": np.tile(np.linspace(0, 19, 20), 10),
        "y": np.random.uniform(1, 5, 200),
        "frame": np.repeat(np.linspace(0, 9, 10), 20),
    }
)
fig = px.line(df, x="x", y="y", animation_frame="frame")
fig.layout.updatemenus[0].buttons[0].args[1]["transition"]["duration"] = 0
fig
```

Comment: This works if I use `fig.show()`, but if I do `fig.write_html('plot.html')` this fails. Is it possible to make this work when the figure is saved to a file?

Comment: works in safari and chrome for me ....  btw that is not your question at all

Comment: For me the behavior is: `fig.show()` this works fine, `fig.write_html("bla.html")` fails, `fig.show()` and then `ctrl+save` in the browser to `bla.html` then it works fine. I have tested both Firefox 93.0, Ubuntu 20.04, and Brave "Version 1.31.87 Chromium: 95.0.4638.54". It seems that the HTML file is not properly generated by `write_html`. 
"btw that is not your question at all" sorry but it is, since I was doing exactly what you posted but did not checked using `fig.show` as I had no clue that the results would be different.

Comment: As this looks like some kind of bug/really strange feature of Plotly, I will accept your answer.